# Get cursor position in a TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield

I want to create a view with a `TextField` whose **default behavior is disabled** (i.e. I don't enable the default keyboard on click).
I created **my own keyboard** because it allows me to do specific actions for my application.
The keyboard works well and populates the `TextField`.

---

**My problem**

I can't manage the blinking `cursor` in the `TextField`. Indeed when I type on my keyboard the `cursor` follows my text so no problem.
On the other hand, **if I decide to click manually in the middle of my text**, the `cursor` moves but the new characters entered do not go to the location of the `cursor`.

How to do this ?

---

**What does it look like ?**

[image]

---

**My code**

*My TextField Widget:*

```
InputAtom(
  autofocus: true,
  controller: controllerInput,
  placeholder: "Placeholder",
  fontSize: 35,
  keyboard: TextInputType.none,
  enableInteractiveSelection: true,
  showCursor: true,
  cursorColor: Colors.red,
  enableSuggestions: false,
  autocorrect: false,
),
```

*My button keyboard example:*

```
KeyboardButtonAtom.numeric({
    Key? key,
    required String text,
    required TextEditingController controller,
  }): super(
    key: key, 
    text: text,
    controller: controller,
    onPressed: (){
      // Here I add the number typed on the keyboard after
      controller.text += text.toString();
      // Here the cursor moves to the end of my controller.text
      controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: controller.text.length);
      print(controller.selection.baseOffset);
    }
  );
```

**How to retrieve the `cursor` position when I type somewhere by hand in my `TextField` to be able to add my numbers from the `cursor` position?**

---

---

**EDIT**

In my `KeyboardButtonAtom`, I do that and it works. Thanks to ***@Kaushik Chandru***
Here is the code that works regardless of the position of the cursor even placed by hand in the middle of your character string

```
String textBeforeCursor = controller.text.substring(0, controller.selection.baseOffset);
String textAfterCursor =  controller.text.substring(controller.selection.extentOffset);
controller.text = textBeforeCursor + text.toString() + textAfterCursor;
int cursorPosition =  textBeforeCursor.length + 1;
controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: cursorPosition);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current position of the cursor you can try

```
var cursorPos = _textEditController.selection.base.offset;

String textAfterCursor =  _textEditController.text.substring(cursorPos);

String textBeforeCursor = _textEditController.text.substring(0, cursorPos);
 _textEditController.text = textBeforeCursor + "someText" + textAfterCursor;
                    
_textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _textEditingController.text.length);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help ! Do you have a track to manage if I do a double tap and I select several characters?